# How to expand a macro in a superscript without curly braces?

Tags: macros, superscripts

Suppose we have

```
\newcommand{\inv}{-1}
```

We want to be able to do `$A^\inv$` instead of `$A^{\inv}$` but that won't work — only the minus sign is superscripted.

Accidentally I stumbled on a possible solution which is to define the macro as

```
\newcommand{\inv}{\kern0pt\relax -1}
```

but since I'm clueless as to why this works or whether this is actually a good solution I decided to ask anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\inv}{\kern0pt\relax -1}
\begin{document}
$A^\inv$ $A^{-1}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand{\inv}{\kern0pt\relax -1}` does *not* work: it gives you two errors!  If you scroll past them, you obtain the output you were looking for merely because of a lucky coincidence.

Comment: `A^{-1}` is as easy to type as `A^\inv`

Comment: Try your “working” version with `$A^\inv A$`

Comment: @egreg I agree that in this case it's probably not worth it, but there are situations in which using a macro could save typing

Comment: See also [Why do I have to put braces around my macro for subscripts / indices? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/556915/why-do-i-have-to-put-braces-around-my-macro-for-subscripts-indices) (and linked question) if the command might take optional argument. (requires some low-level TeX programming however.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a pair of braces inside the definition of `\inv` should work.

```
 \newcommand{\inv}{{-1}}
```

Now, when you do `A^\inv`, it will expand to `A^{-1}` instead of `A^-1`.

Comment: Depends on the particular operation this might have other disadvantages [math mode - How to avoid using curly braces when placing a \DeclareMathOperator command in subscript or superscript, while preserving spacing? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437378/how-to-avoid-using-curly-braces-when-placing-a-declaremathoperator-command-in-s)

Answer (score 2):

I think that, for this cases, it's better to give the command “active” control over the output. So I would use `\inv{A}`, read as *inverse of `A`*. That way you have *full* control over the output.

```
\newcommand*\inv[1]{#1^{-1}}
$\inv{A}$
```

The difference between `A^\inv` and `\inv{A}` is that in the first case you have to adjust `\inv` to be taken correctly by `^`, whereas in the second you give `\inv` full power.

I would consider the “passive” approach only if it benefits the readability (and doesn't harm maintenance) of the code. Consider the absurd example

```
a + b % preferred
\add{a}{b} % easily to manage, but far less readble
```

In this case, `\inv{A}` doesn't harm readability / ease-of-understanding in my opinion, so I would go for that.

Comment: In the past I used this approach and found that the formulas were hard to read, especially when `A` is a long expression or when used in conjunction with other superscripts such as transpose symbols. And then I noticed that TeX's `\prime` is defined as a "passive" superscript so I decided to give it a try.

Comment: The reason `\prime` exists is because it's easier to program `'` that way, I don't think that you should take that as an example / justification. But yes, in case you find it difficult to read, then Peter's solution is the way to go ;)