# How to avoid using curly braces when placing a \DeclareMathOperator command in subscript or superscript, while preserving spacing?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, macros, subscripts, superscripts

Let's say in my preamble I define `\DeclareMathOperator\rad{rad}` and have the text

```
Let $f$ be a smooth function and $f^{\rad}$ its radial symmetrization.
```

It is inconvenient to have to enclose the `\rad` in curly braces. I could work around it by defining it as `\newcommand\rad{{\operatorname{rad}}}` instead. But at another place in my document I write

```
Let $n$ be a positive integer and $2 \rad(n)$ be twice its radical.
```

If I use `\newcommand\rad{{\operatorname{rad}}}`, there is no space between `2` and `rad`. (See [newcommand vs. DeclareMathOperator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67506))

So my question is: How can I allow a command to be used directly in superscript or subscript, while preserving the correct spacing when it is appears in the middle of a formula?

---

Related: [Double subscript error with \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109420)

Comment: enclosing `\rad` in braces shouldn't be seen as inconvenient, it is the (only) documented syntax for `^` in latex, which takes a brace delimited argument. The latex book always shows `x^{2}` for example even though `x^2` works due to implementation details and lack of error checking.

Comment: there we go...`\^([^{\\]|\\[a-zA-Z]*)`

Comment: Remark: There's always the option of globally search-and-replace the document *in LaTeX itself instead of externally*, or maybe making `^` (and `_`) math-active, but they have other disadvantages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just use `\rad` in exponents and not really as an operator, then defining

```
\newcommand{\rad}{{\mathrm{rad}}}
```

will let you type

```
f^\rad
```

Note that `\DeclareMathOperator` is not a shorthand for getting `\mathrm`.

If you need `\rad` as an operator in other contexts, then no, you can't, for the same reason that `^\notin` will produce an error.

On the other hand, is there a real reason for sparing a couple of braces? Any good TeX editor will supply the braces as soon as you enter `^`. Adding them *always* will save you from head scratching when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Why in the world would you use the same macro, `\rad`, for two completely different and unrelated operations, radical and radial symmetrization, just because both happen to start with the letters “rad”? Use different macros for semantically different operations. Apart from avoiding situations such as the one you describe, it also makes it easier to search trough the document for e.g. all occurrences of radial symmetrizations. You could even program these commands to automatically add entries to the index whenever they are used.

With regard to the question of `f^\radial` vs. `f^{\radial}`, do yourself a favour and always brace upper and lower indices, unless perhaps if you are dealing with extremely simple situations such as `a_0`, `x^2`, `p_i`, etc. It will be less error-prone, and frankly, `f^\radial` just looks weird, like something that only accidentally works (which is actually the case, as demonstrated by you).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator\rad{rad}
    % I would have used "\radical",
    % but this is already defined.

\newcommand\radial{{\mathrm{rad}}}

\begin{document}

\( \rad(n) = f^{\radial} \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for advising to use different semantic syntaxes when the same output means two different things.

Answer (score 0):

This is an analysis on why it's impossible if `\rad` is "just" a macro.

(of course you can [redefine the dollar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59980) or redefine `^` and `_` to be an active character etc., in which case it isn't too difficult, but it isn't covered here)

---

First, if you work through the source code and fully expand out the normal definition of `\operatorname{rad}`, it's equivalent to

```
\mathop{
    \newmcodes@
    \kern\z@
    \operator@font
    rad
} \nolimits@
```

Then, the code used to scan for a math subformula after a `^` is the following:

[image: scan_math procedure in TeX]

As you can see the allowed options are (only `cur_cmd` is considered thus implicit and explicit character token are both accepted)

- something of catcode letter or other, or something `\chardef`ed: either

  - its `\mathcode` is used (not useful to typeset multiple characters), or
  - if the mathcode is `"8000` then it's recursively expanded as an active character. (reduces to other cases. The bracing does not help, try yourself:

  ```
  \mathcode `c="8000
  {\catcode`c\active\gdef c{ab}}
  $2^c$
  ```

  this code results in `2ab` being typesetted)
- `\char ⟨number⟩`: not useful, as above.
- `\mathchar ⟨number⟩`: not useful, as above.
- something `\mathchardef`ed: not useful, as above.
- `\delimiter ⟨number⟩`: not useful.
- `{ ... }`.

In the last case, the token must be `{`, and we recall that in normal context this will make it a `\mathord`
(that is `{,}` is the same as `\mathord,`).

By the table of math spacing rules:

[image: TeX by topic, table of math spacing rules]

normally `2\rad` will make it the case of row 0:ord and column 1:op, which *always* inserts "1:thin space"
(regardless of math style)
and `2{...}` will make it the case of row 0:ord and column 0:ord = no space.

We can manually insert a `\thinspace` but this is obviously wrong when used in other cases e.g. a exponent.
Even detecting the current mathstyle (with `\mathchoice`) can't help.

---

For academical purpose, it is probably also possible (without redefining either `$` or `^` as I mentioned above)
if you create a font such that some single glyph has
the 3 characters `rad`, then proceed to define `\rad` to be a single `\mathchardef` of it.