# How to define a command that can be used as a superscript without {} and that can have a subscript

Tags: math-mode, macros, spacing, subscripts, superscripts

I have used `\theta` hundreds of times in my document. Now I decided that I would like all thetas to be in red color.

So I would like to redefine the command `\theta` to create a red theta.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\let\oldtheta\theta
\renewcommand{\theta}{\mathcolor{red}{\oldtheta}}
\newcommand{\thetaWrongSpacing}{{\mathcolor{red}{\oldtheta}}}


\begin{document}

$M^\theta$ %gives error message
$\theta_1\oldtheta_1$ %works perfectly
$M^\thetaWrongSpacing$ %works perfectly
$\thetaWrongSpacing_1$ %wrong spacing
$M^\alpha$ % seems to work perfectly, but David Carlisle says this should not be used according to the LaTeX manual

\end{document}
```

but then `$M^\theta$` results in an error. I can fix this by enclosing the definition of the command with `{}`, but then the spacing is not correct.

How can I redefine `\theta` in the preamble without making any change within the document?

PS:
`\renewcommand{\theta}{\begingroup\mathcolor{red}{\oldtheta}\endgroup}` does also produce an error for `$M^\theta$` and flaws the spacing of `\theta_1`.

Comment: note that `^\theta` is not supported latex syntax (you are supposed to use braces)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle , but $M^\alpha$ does not give any error message in Overleaf and is commonmly used by my coauthors and me.

Comment: I can't see the difference between `$M^\oldtheta$` and `$M^\thetaWrongSpacing$`.

Comment: in some simple cases it might seem to work, but, as you see here, it does not work in general and the latex manual never mentions that syntax.

Comment: @Stephen Yes, I agree, but `$\thetaWrongSpacing_1$` has wrong spacing.

Comment: @Jakob for a simpler example try `\newcommand\hmm{10}  $M^{\hmm} = M^\hmm$`

Comment: Only because some syntax is commonly used doesn't necessarily mean it is correct ... There are lots of examples where syntax is still abundantly used despite being deprecated.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, this example is quite obvious, but I don't want to have a sequence of cahracters, I just want to change the color. (If there would be a possibility to also group sequences of characters for ^ without cahnging the spacing, this would be great too.)

Comment: I see that this commonly used syntax is officially wrong and we shoudl not use it in teh future, but I would still be interested if there is a fix for my problem (other than search and replace all `^\theta` by `^{\theta}` and to convince my coauthors not to use `^\theta` anymore.

Comment: You could switch to an editor that supports "replace all",

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, I used "replace all" (which is supprted by Overleaf), but now I have to hope that my coauthors don't run into trouble when using `^\theta` in future.

Comment: Suspect duplicate of [math mode - How to avoid using curly braces when placing a \DeclareMathOperator command in subscript or superscript, while preserving spacing? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437378/how-to-avoid-using-curly-braces-when-placing-a-declaremathoperator-command-in-s?noredirect=1&lq=1). (see also the linked questions)

Answer (score 2):

The reason of bad spacing with colorized theta in you example is due to old concept of colors implementation. The colors in pdftex or XeTeX is based on inserted `\pdcolorstack`s (roughly speaking). They must be inserted when a color change starts and when the color is returned back, then it is inserted too. Roughly speaking:

```
{color-change text}_subscript
```

expands to

```
{pdfcolorstack text}pdfcolorstack_subscript
```

and the secnod `pdfcolorstack` is the reason of the problem.

On the other hand, if we are using a modern concept of colors (using attributes, provided by LuaTeX), then there isn't problem with spacing. For example, in OpTeX:

```
\let\oritheta=\theta

\def\theta{{\Red\oritheta}}

Test $a^\theta$ and $\theta_1$.
\bye
```

Spacing is correct. Or you can use LuaLaTeX with appropriate coloring package based on color attributes.

Note1: your macro with `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` doesn't solve the spacing problem for subscripts. The `\pdfcolorstack` is here too and the unwanted kern 0.2779pt (from italic correction of theta) is here too. Your comment "works perfectly" in your source file isn't true.

Note2 (due to the discussion here): TeX was designed for humans, they create and read the source files of TeX. It is much more comfortable to write `$M^\theta$` than `$M^{\theta}$`. So, we cannot prohibit the first syntax which is more suitable for humans.

Comment: Consistency also helps humans make less syntax mistakes. Is it possible to add some minimal code with Lua attributes to demonstrate the method used by OpTeX?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides the code snnipet that ends with `\bye` is the method to be used with OpTeX. The format use lua attributes for colors, and has color support by default.

Comment: @wipet I have updated my question. Now everything is correct again I think. (I didn't had the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` inside in the original question, so I removed it again and updated the PS)

Answer (score 1):

As wipet mentioned, you can use Lua attributes to color the glyphs without changing the spacing. In LaTeX you can do that using the package `luacolor`.

### Result with `xcolor`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\let\oldtheta\theta
\renewcommand*{\theta}{{\mathcolor{red}\oldtheta}}

\begin{document}    
    $M^\theta M^\oldtheta$
    
    $\theta_1 \oldtheta_1$
    
    % check that the spacing is the same 
    $M^\theta$\llap{$M^\oldtheta$}
    
    $\theta_1$\llap{$\oldtheta_1$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Result with `luacolor`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacolor}

\let\oldtheta\theta
\renewcommand*{\theta}{{\color{red}\oldtheta}}

\begin{document}    
    $M^\theta M^\oldtheta$
    
    $\theta_1 \oldtheta_1$
    
    % check that the spacing is the same 
    $M^\theta$\llap{$M^\oldtheta$}
    
    $\theta_1$\llap{$\oldtheta_1$}
\end{document}
```

[image]